# Android studio Java method parameter indentation with annotation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, indentation

How can i configure Android Studio to indent the method parameters by previous parameter? For example, i want something like this:

```
public static class EventObject {
  public final String eventType;
  public final Object eventData;

  public EventObject(@EventType final String eventType,
                                final Object eventData) {
    this.eventType = eventType;
    this.eventData = eventData;
  }
}
```

But Android Studio reformats it like this:

```
public static class EventObject {
  public final String eventType;
  public final Object eventData;

  public EventObject(@EventType final String eventType,
                     final Object eventData) {
    this.eventType = eventType;
    this.eventData = eventData;
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as Android Studio is concerned, you ARE wrapping to the previous parameter. If you continued to add parameters to `EventObject`, they would be inline. The `@EventType` annotation is part of the `eventType` parameter.
Please note a couple of things though: `EventObject` is already a class in  the `java.util` library, so consider renaming your class; `static` classes should only ever be internal classes.

Comment: It is already inner class, thanks. I want to wrap to beginning of parameter declaration right after the annotation end

Comment: The thing is, as far as the IDE (and any other developers looking at your code) is concerned; the annotation is part of the declaration. So unless the framework you're using supports using annotations after parameter declaration (unlikely) you won't be able to change it. RE: inner class; Cool! Just wanted to make sure.